# Convert client requests to proper requests for custom highchart node export server

Tags: python, flask, highcharts

Im trying to export images by a custom node export server. server is running and when I send requests directly to server everything is fine.

```
    exporting: {
    url: "http://ip:7779"
},
```

But for some security reasons first I need to send request to my flask server, I checked incoming request and it contain this values:

```
CombinedMultiDict([ImmutableMultiDict([]), ImmutableMultiDict([('width', u'0'), ('scale', u'2'), ('type', u'image/png'), ('filename', u'chart'), ('svg', u'<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" class="highcharts-root" ...omited!')])
```

and content type is like `multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryt7Gcilm12pNBmSab`

so I changed my code:

```
    url: "/highchart"
},
```

```
@app.route('/highchart', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def highchart_export():
    try:
        data = {}
        for i in request.values:
            data[i] = request.values[i]
        response = requests.post('http://0.0.0.0:7779',data=data)
        return response.text, response.status_code, response.headers.items()
    except:
        print traceback.format_exc(sys.exc_info())
```

But it not work. I just get an image with text "*It appears that we don't support this file format.*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems in my code some headers and part of body is missing so for a clean redirect I used this code:

```
response = requests.request(
    method=request.method,
    url='http://127.0.0.1:7779',
    headers={key: value for (key, value) in request.headers},
    data=request.get_data(),
    cookies=request.cookies,
    allow_redirects=False)
headers = [(name, value) for (name, value) in response.raw.headers.items()]
return Response(response.content, response.status_code, headers)
```

And now output is fine.